# Artix linux static sound from speakers when no sound is playing

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, artix-linux

On my artix (base-runit-20210101) install I have static noise coming out of my sub-woofer when no sound is playing. This problem started around January. I tried different distros: on Manjaro KDE (20.2.1) this problem doesn't appear, but on Pop_OS GNOME (20.10) this problem appears.

Comment: Recently, there has been a little revolution in Linux audio component thanks Pipewire advent. We are still in a transition period, where not all distros offer that software. It's important to specify which software and its version your tried distros provided.

Comment: @mattia.b89 I tested Pipewire and found that with that software there's no static sound coming out of my sub-woofer.
Also I added distro versions in the question.